# Google maps static api - Marker doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I got a static map link using this wizard http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html and the marker is on the image, but when i put this link into my website, the marker doesn't show up.

Here is the website where i'm trying to view the map. I see the map, but no marker. http://church.allthingswebdesign.com

I just have the link in an image tag like this

```
<img id="map" src="http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=43.963415,-92.460594&zoom=14&markers=Comfort+Suites,+4141+Maine+Ave+SE,+Rochester,+MN++55904&size=300x400&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&key=ABQIAAAA6-Rq-t8XwsqXeXws3DleLBSI_7XewNJfovQwsmZjGMbTG7rp6BQaj3bwm-gy7nGQPyWKPTd3zPtcVA" alt="Map" />
```

Why doesn't the marker show up on my website?

Comment: If you manually browse to the url generated by the wizard, does the marker show? can you clarify how you're embedding it in the page?

As an aside, have a look at http://www.lipsum.com/ for placeholder text :)

Comment: I tried manually browsing the url like you said and the marker wasn't there. I needed to set the sensor parameter to true or false.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify did setting it to true/false solve the problem for you? It didn't when I tested but I then went back and re-generated the URL using the wizard and appended your API key... It seems to have worked.

Comment: Oh and one handy trick if you use firefox - you can right-click on the image shown in the wizard (the one with the marker) and select "View Image". This is an easy way to find the URL of the image in question. View source alone wouldn't do this as the source code is changed by javascript when you change settings in the wizard

Comment: Yes the sensor parameter did work.

Comment: in that case, would you mind marking my answer as correct? thanks

Comment: Sorry. I meant to do that last night but it told me to wait 16 minutes and i forgot.

Comment: No worries - good luck with the rest of the site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, one thing to change - where it says `TRUE_OR_FALSE` in the url try changing it to `false` (all lower case).

If I browse directly to the url of the image provided, I don't see a marker so I suspect it's a problem with the wizard rather than your site.

Try this:

```
<img src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.962072,-92.456297&zoom=13&markers=43.962072,-92.456297&size=300x400&sensor=false&key=ABQIAAAA6-Rq-t8XwsqXeXws3DleLBSI_7XewNJfovQwsmZjGMbTG7rp6BQaj3bwm-gy7nGQPyWKPTd3zPtcVA">
```

[image]

For details on the sensor parameter, [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/load?hl=ja-jp#the_sensor_parameter)

Comment: what does the sensor parameter do even?